# What is a term for non-functional predictable relationships?

Tags: functions

There are many relationships and equations that can be predicted. However are non-functions. Examples would include:

- Graphing a circle
- Square and other even-number roots

Is there a term to distinguish this from all relationships and equations? What is that term?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function

Comment: @Chappers You could write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are normally called [multivalued functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function). They can arise as the inverse of a surjective map (as in the example $x \mapsto x^{n}$ for even $n$), but, as your circle example shows, the inverse of a multivalued function is in general also a multivalued function.

(Making sense of the concept generally in the complex plane lead Riemann to his [surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface), where the idea is to extend a relationship $f(z,w)=0$ to the largest "natural" space.)