# Term for non-function relationship

Tags: statistics, functions

Is there a term for non-function relationships where the relationship is statistical in nature? In this question ([What is a term for non-functional predictable relationships?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986607/what-is-a-term-for-non-functional-predictable-relationships)) it is established that the correct term for some of these (e.g. the graph of a circle) is a `Multivalued Function`. However, in my case, the relationship is more complex and statistical, and I do not think that the term `Multivalued Function` seems precise.

Here is [an example of such a relationship borrowed Chapter 7 of "An Introduction to Statistical Learning"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlMS7.png).

In the example in the link, there is a clear relationship between wage and age, but it is not a function. For example, at the age of 50, a person is likely to have a wage between 50-175, with a small probability of a wage of ~275.

**My Question**

In the example link above:

"Wage is a **blank** of age". What is the correct word for **blank**?

Comment: I would just say it's a relation.

Comment: @Adrian, I don't think that is a technical term. Is there a more technical/precise term?

Comment: A relation is a subset of points in the $xy$ plane. It is definitely a technical term, though it certainly might not be as precise as you're seeking. Maybe you're after the concept of a correlation?

Comment: @Adrian, I did not realize relation was a technical term. After quick googling (https://study.com/academy/lesson/relation-in-math-definition-examples.html) it clearly is. Do you know if the term relation is can be applied to more dimensions. For example "Wage is a relation of age, gender and education".

Comment: It can definitely apply to more dimensions, but it is a pretty general term. It's simply a set of points - ANY set of points. What you're wanting to say, if I read you right, is that there's a pattern in these points such that, if you know the value of several variables, that can narrow down where another variable is. Is that correct? If so, I would say that the final variable is correlated with the others.

Comment: My problem with correlated is 3 fold: 1. correlated is a little too precise for what I mean (it could be anti correlated etc.) 2. correlation does not capture the non-linearity of the example. Saying Wage correlates with age is only true in a subset of the data and is not true in many of the points. Finally, it doesn't work in the sentence "Wage is a correlation of age". If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it, although I agree that relation is not the best term either.

Comment: I would say that the term "correlation" is more flexible than you're saying, primarily because (thinking as a machine learning guy, here) you can correlate any features you want. Consider $y=x^2$. Are $x$ and $y$ correlated? Well, not linearly, but the feature $y$ is highly correlated with the feature $x^2$.

Comment: You are correct on some level, but, strictly speaking, in the equation for a circle (and many other relationships) there is no correlation at all, despite a strong "relationship". Multivalued function relation (or something like that) is probably more accurate, although you are also right that it is super general. It sounds like the term I want does not precisely exist and that I should improvise.

Comment: For a circle, the feature $y^2$ is highly correlated with the feature $x^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the term you're looking for is "correlated". This is a highly flexible term that means one variable or feature is related to another. That is, knowing the value of one variable or feature enables you to know better the value of the correlated variable or feature.